# How can I read a text file from DCIM folder( named as temp.txt) using Kotlin Android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, file

Can someone help to find problem following code snnipet?
In AndroidManifest.xml I added.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

then I tried in mainactivity.kt

```
val fileName = "temp.txt"
val dcimDir = File(
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString()
)
val file = File(dcimDir, "temp.txt")
Log.d("Flag",file.exists().toString())
val text = StringBuilder()
try {
    val br = BufferedReader(FileReader(file))
    var line: String?
    while (br.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
        text.append(line)
        text.append('\n')
        //Log.d("String2","text.toString()")
    }
    br.close()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    Log.d("Exception",e.printStackTrace().toString())
}
Log.d("String1",text.toString())
```

but after running the app inside **Logcat** String1 showed empty, It didn't showed what written inside the text file and the run log showed "**W/System: A resource failed to call close.** "

what's wrong with the code?

screenshot of Logcat:
[image]

Edit:
**The file do exists.**

[image]
But it can not be read. May be because of permission problem. I already added permission to Manifest.xml
After adding  `Log.d("Exception",e.printStackTrace().toString())` to catch section.

LogCat showed
[image]

I've checked android developer [site](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-any) I tried to allowed all but my app has only media allowed option.
[image]

The file do exists.

[image]

Comment: `//You'll need to add proper error handling here
}` Well its time you do. Print the stacktrace. Log the message. Toast() the message to the user so the user is informed.

Comment: Furter: use dcimDir.exists() and dcimDir.canRead() before you try to read.

Comment: I've used the dcimDir.exists() and print in the log. Even file.exists() showed true in the Logcat.

`Log.d("Flag",file.exists().toString())`

log showed

2023-03-04 19:11:46.208  8652-8652  Flag                    com.hamker.quizer                    D  true

Comment: File found. Problem in Try block.

Comment: Post your new code with all the hints you got.

Comment: Use file.canRead() before read.

Comment: file.canRead() return false.

Comment: Is this because of permission?
I already added 

`<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"
        />`

in AndroidManifet.xml

Comment: We are waiting for a code update.

Comment: Please check the latest update.

Comment: If the file does not exist you should not try to read it. And you blindly continue to read.

Comment: Log.d("Flag",file.exists().toString()) showed True. The file do exists. But I cannot read it.